# SQL outer join scenario - seemed simple when it was proposed

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a <strike>little</strike> lot rusty with my SQL and this is driving me nuts.  What in my head is a simple outer join for some reason isn't working.

t1:
column1, column2
101, 1
101, 2
101, 3
102, 2

t2:
column1, column2
1, one
2, two
3, three
4, four

(Where t1.column2 -> t2.column1)

Given the tables above the dataset I'm looking for would be:
101, one
101, two
101, three
101, null

102, null
102, two
102, null
102, null

Maybe I'm over thinking it, I don't know. I'm trying to get back 4 rows for any select, in this example where t1.column1=101 or t1.column1=102 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  td.column1,
  CASE WHEN t1.column2 IS NOT NULL THEN t2.column2 END AS column2
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM t1) AS td
CROSS JOIN t2
LEFT JOIN  t1 ON t1.column1 = td.column1 AND t1.column2 = t2.column1
```

A variation on the above (suggested by [ypercube](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344949/ypercube) in the comments):

```
SELECT
  t1_d.column1,
  t2_2.column2
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM t1) AS t1_d
CROSS JOIN t2
LEFT JOIN  t1
  INNER JOIN t2 AS t2_2 ON t1.column2 = t2_2.column1
ON t1.column1 = t1_d.column1 AND t1.column2 = t2.column1
```

Comment: Turned out similar to @ruakh's, which I didn't realise at first.

Comment: @ypercube: Thanks for the edit, but your version was as mistaken as my original one. To achieve the OP's output, the first column should be taken from `td`, and the second one (which is expected to contain NULLs) from `t1`.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Still, the answer does not give 100% what the OP asked for. There should be one more Join to `t2`, so `'two'` is shown and not `2`.

Comment: @ypercube: Absolutely, thank you! Alternatively it could be done like in my updated answer.

Comment: I must say, it is so easy to get confused with all these meaningless `column1`, `columnX` names.

Comment: Yeah, so true. But come on, you had such a nice CROSS-LEFT join combination. It would be so much nicer with one more (INNER) join :) How often do you get the chance to combine 3 types in one query?

Comment: @ypercube: Ah, so tempting indeed! :) But if you insist on *inner* join, it will have to be incorporated differently: `… LEFT JOIN (t1 INNER JOIN t2 AS t2_2 ON t1.column2 = t2_2.column1) ON t1.column1 = td.column1 AND t1.column2 = t2.column1`, and so the nice pattern of joins would be broken. :) Otherwise it would have to be another (left) outer join, to keep all the rows returned by the previous left join.

Comment: Yes, that was my intention. The (parentheses-not-needed) INNER JOIN in the middle.

Comment: Colour me impressed, this works perfectly.  Thanks for taking the time to help out, I learned a lot.  I actually had to look up cross join, I've never used it before.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you want is:

```
SELECT sq.column1,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS
                  ( SELECT 1
                      FROM t1
                     WHERE column1 = sq.column1
                       AND column2 = t2.column1
                  )
            THEN t2.column2
        END
  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT
                column1
           FROM t1
       ) sq
 CROSS
  JOIN t2
;
```

Comment: cross joins are not a good idea if they can be avoided, especially since that is not really the result you want. Performance will be terrible if the tables become large.

Comment: @dbenham: Agreed that cross-joins are not very desirable in general, but that is what essentially what the question asks for.  If there are N rows in t1 and M rows in t2, the answer will consist of N × M rows, the same as a cross-product will consist of N × M rows.

Comment: @Andriy has simplified the Cross Join approach.

Comment: @JonathanLeffle: Thanks - I totally missed the cross join aspect of the problem until I saw Andriy's solution (the superior answer in IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.column1, t2.column2
  FROM t2 JOIN t1 ON t1.column2 = t2.column1
UNION
SELECT t2.column2 AS column1, NULL AS column2
  FROM t2
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                      FROM t1
                     WHERE t1.column2 = t2.column1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   t1.column1, t2.column2
FROM t1
   LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.column2 = t2.column1
```

that should do it?

Comment: That gives you only five rows as a result (rows 1-4 and 6 in resultset listed in the question), not all eight.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you wanted to get 4 rows back. Sounds like you might want to have t2 drive the query so look at RIGHT JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN